# Single installation with sub-domains for admin and separate domains for sites

Tags: multisite

I'd like to use a single installation of wordpress, and achieve the following:

- site.com is the main host site
- other-site1.com
- ...
- other-sitex.com are the other sites and show their fronts. login access should be disabled / prevented - I assume I could do this using the server conf file.
- admin1.site.com
- ...
- adminx.site.com are the admin for the above sites

As far as I understand, I need to use a combination of wordpress multisite for the subdomains, as well as possibly a plugin for the separate domains. Or, could i do some sort of fancy redirect server-side for the urls?

I'd like the accounts to be unique to each subdomain / site if possible, or at worse, granted admin privileges only to specific domains.

Answer (score 0):

First, as you already said, you will need to activate multisite. To do so in your wp-config.php file just **before** the line that says: `/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */` add `define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );` and then in the WordPress admin, go to Tools >Network Setup then follow the steps to finish installing multisite. Then use this plugin to map the domin names: [WordPress MU Domain Mapping](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/)

Check out this article for more details and some other plugins to help manage multisites: [The Ultimate Guide to WordPress Multisite](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/ultimate-guide-multisite/)

Comment: mu domain mapping plugin: Last Updated: 1 year ago

Comment: the last active support topic for this plugin was active less that 24 hours ago so I wouldn't worry about it being out of date